# Oozie pyspark action using Spark 1.6 instead of 2.2

Tags: pyspark, oozie

When run from the command line using spark2-submit its running under Spark version 2.2.0. But when i use a oozie spark action its running under Spark version 1.6.0 and failing with error **TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable**

My oozie spark action below

```
<!-- Spark action first -->
    <action name="foundationorder" cred="hcat">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <job-xml>${hiveConfig}</job-xml>
            <master>yarn-cluster</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>OrderFill</name>
            <jar>${envRoot}/oozie/scripts/pyscripts/orders_fill.py</jar>
            <spark-opts>--py-files ${envRoot}/oozie/scripts/pyscripts/order_fill.zip
                --files ${hiveConfig}                
                --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/bin/
                --conf spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME=/data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/bin/
            </spark-opts>
            <arg>${Arg1}</arg>
            <arg>${Arg2}</arg>
            <arg>${Arg3}</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="sendEmailKill"/>
        <error to="sendEmailKill"/>
    </action>
```

I have mentioned oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=spark2 in the job.properties file
Please advise how to force Oozie to use spark2

Comment: Asking multiple but similar questions will not help you, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569685/not-able-to-run-pyspak-action-from-oozie-yarn

Comment: Which kind of distro do you use - CDH, HDP, CDP, Apache, custom-built? Which version of distro and/or Oozie? If Cloudera / Horton, did you search their forums for that kind of issue?